# Replicate single table from Postgres 9.3 replica

Tags: postgresql

I have an existing Postgres 9.3 server acting as a read-only replica using the built-in streaming replication.

I need to replicate a single table from a database on that server to another physical server.

I've tried using bucardo but it doesn't like talking to read-only databases.

Is there a way to trigger an update on the remote server from the replica?

Comment: I suggest use Londiste3  replicate a single table from primary db.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to replicate the table from the read/write master.

PostgreSQL's built-in physical streaming replication can only replicate the whole database server instance.

The replication systems that support single-table replication require the ability to use a trigger to write a record of changes. This can only be done on the upstream read/write master.

The [BDR project](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide) plans to deliver a unidirectional version that can stream changes using only the transaction logs, with individual table selection. That would meet your needs, but it won't be ready for a few months at best, possibly longer. Keep an eye out on the PostgreSQL mailing lists and the above wiki for discussion of "UDR" if you're interested.